# Default function parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hi I have to admit that I am still grasping many ES6 syntax even though I have used a fair amount of them.
For example, I understand that you can do `console.log(multiply(5))`   to get the result of a given function of

```
function multiply(a, b = 1) {
  return a * b;
}
```

But let say you have

```
function multiply(a, b = 1, c) {
  return a * b * c;
}
```

Obviously you can't do `(console.log(multiply(5,,5))`. In this case, is rearranging the arguments position in the function to become `function multiply(a, c, b = 1)`  the only possible way? Or is there any other smarter way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters

Like you can see here, try to run it.

Comment: default parameters must be the last ones to be defined. or you call it like *multiply(1, undefined, 2)*

Comment: @AZ_ default parameters can be anywhere in the argument list. Did you confuse it with the spread operator?

Comment: @SebastiaanYN I meant its a good practice to do so, that's why I have added how you will have to call the function with params with default values defined in between.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your wonderful answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `undefined` to use default values:

```
function multiply(a, b = 1, c) {
  return a * b * c;
}

multiply(2, undefined, 3); // 6
```

You can read about default parameter values and see more examples [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to pass a *single object* with default property assignment instead of multiple separate arguments:

```js
function multiply({ a, b = 1, c }) {
  return a * b * c;
}

console.log(multiply({
  a: 3,
  b: 4,
  c: 5
}));
console.log(multiply({
  a: 3,
  c: 5
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set your default parameter to be the first one, and then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). One benefit to this is that you're now not limited to just 3 numbers;

```js
    function multiply(a = 1, ...args) {
        args = [a, ...args];

        return args.reduce((x, y) => x * y);
    }

    console.log(multiply(5));
    console.log(multiply(5, 10, 15, 20, 25));
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, JS doesn't support elisions (skips) on function arguments, so you can't simply write

```
f(1,,2)
```

and expect the 2nd argument to be the default. You could use array elisions instead:

```js
function f(a, b = 99, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c)
}


f(...[1,,2])
```

Not sure if this is worth the trouble though.

As @Dave Marshall mentioned, the most straightforward way it to pass `undefined`, I'd use it in a more readable form, that makes it clear which parameter is omitted:

```js
function f(a, b = 99, c) {
  console.log(a, b, c)
}


f(1, void 'b', 2)
```